# Methods return type in C#

Tags: c#, visual-studio, function, methods, opc

i am using a method to retrieve data from an OPC DA server using TitaniumAS packages, the problem i am having is that i have a lot of tags to read/write so i have to use methods.
The WriteX method works fines as it doesnt have to return anything but the read does not, well it does its job, it reads but i cannot use that data outside of the method because it was a void method, when i tried to use it as a String method (that's the type of data i need) it says :

Error   CS0161  'ReadX(string, string)': not all code paths return a value
PS : note that i am just a beginner in C#

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Common;
using TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Da;
using TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Da.Browsing;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Channels;
using Async;

namespace OPCDA
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            TitaniumAS.Opc.Client.Bootstrap.Initialize();

            Uri url = UrlBuilder.Build("Kepware.KEPServerEX.V6");

            using (var server = new OpcDaServer(url))
            {
                server.Connect();

                OpcDaGroup group = server.AddGroup("MyGroup");
                group.IsActive = true;

                Ascon ascon1 = new Ascon();
               
               ReadX("Channel1.Ascon1.AsconS", ascon1.ALM);
               Console.WriteLine("value = {0}", ascon1.ALM);

                void WriteX(String Link, String Ascon)
                {
                    var definition1 = new OpcDaItemDefinition
                    {
                        ItemId = Link,
                        IsActive = true
                    };

                    OpcDaItemDefinition[] definitions = { definition1 };
                    OpcDaItemResult[] results = group.AddItems(definitions);



                    OpcDaItem tag = group.Items.FirstOrDefault(i => i.ItemId == Link);
                    OpcDaItem[] items = { tag };
                    
                    object[] Values = { Ascon };
                    HRESULT[] Results = group.Write(items, Values);

                }
                string ReadX(String Link, String read)
                {
                    var definition1 = new OpcDaItemDefinition
                    {
                        ItemId = Link,
                        IsActive = true
                    };

                    OpcDaItemDefinition[] definitions = { definition1 };
                    OpcDaItemResult[] results = group.AddItems(definitions);
                    OpcDaItemValue[] values = group.Read(group.Items, OpcDaDataSource.Device);

                    read = Convert.ToString(values[0].Value);
                   
                    
                }
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `ReadX` does not have a return statement. Maybe you meant to `return read;`? Perhaps it is easier to read when you create the methods on the class level instead of inside the Main method.

Comment: I just tried it, the error is gone but I still cant read it outside of the method, i want to transfer that `return read` to `ascon.ALM`

Comment: @Seyl Passing a value to a method, like a string, will not keep a reference to the original property (`ascon1.ALM`). You should look up tutorials on the subject of return values and how references work in C#.

Comment: @Silvermind, i did the return as you said, and it now works, thank you

Comment: i am gonna edit the post to show how it worked

Comment: @Seyl Please do not update your question with the solution. Consider rewriting your question where you at least show some basic understanding. Then add an answer to your own question and accept that.

Comment: do some steps:
1- write your method outside of Main.
2- remove the `string read` parameter from `ReadX` method.
3- replace `read = Convert.ToString(values[0].Value);` by `return Convert.ToString(values[0].Value);`.
4- use `ReadX` method like this `ascon1.ALM=ReadX("Channel1.Ascon1.AsconS");` in `Main` method.

Comment: @Seyl You seem to have posted two questions, [are they similar?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74768836) Have you solved it, because that question seems to lack information, if you post it repeatedly, please delete the previous question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the first step was to state the return like this :
`return Convert.ToString(values[0].Value)` instead of  `read = Convert.ToString(values[0].Value)`

then go up and use that value with my variable :
 `ascon1.ALM=ReadX("Channel1.Ascon1.AsconS");`